# Non-unique ids on a page allowed in webcomponents

Tags: javascript, dom, web-component

Are non unique DOM element ids allowed in web components? I get that these are allowed in different documents but I'm experiencing this issue on youtube.com. Specifically all the sidebar elements have id 'endpoint' and each element has the same `ownerDocument` (the window.document)

Comment: They're "allowed" in that the browser will deal with it, but they won't work properly.

Comment: `id` attributes must be unique, per document. If your web components use a shadow dom then _inside that shadow dom_ you can use ids that also occur withing the document (because you can't query into a shadow dom from the outside), but given that your web component is entirely in controls of its own content, it should already know exactly where the elements they need to access are. There is no need for query selecting inside a shadow dom, build your shadow dom using normal node api functions and cache them in scope to the web component.

Comment: Incorrect. Duplicate IDs are valid since very early Internet-Explorer days when it created **global variables** for all ID values. 
All Browser vendors copied this behavior, many moons ago, because once Microsoft owned 90% of the Browser market, and all Browsers had to support Web applications written on top of this (Microsoft) ID behavior. Today, all Browsers but FireFox still create a totally valid global Array of IDs for duplicates IDs. ``this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("#foo")`` will return all elements with the same ID=foo inside shadowDOM... but those will not create any variables!

Comment: Right it seems I can't find a shadow root in the webcomponents on youtube.com and document.querySelectorAll('#endpoint') gives me an array of elements. Safe to assume theres no shadow root and youtube is just disregarding id uniqueness as set by https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-id ?

Comment: Yes  **document.** ``querySelector/getElementById`` queries the main DOM, it can't query shadowRoots

Answer (score 1):

YouTube uses `Polymer.js` to form their own web components which have their own shadowDOM. If you keep an eye on the elements in DevTools you'll see different tagnames and loads of the same ids due to many components containing a shadowDOM.

Best bet is to target an element with their tagName using:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('ytd-stupidVariableName-here')
```

Otherwise, try and combine classnames & ids to find exactly the element you're after.